# WPF Theme Generic.xaml not being applied - despite standard config

Tags: c#, wpf, viewmodel, datatemplate

I've got a class library with all the standard WPF references added and we're using a ViewModel first approach whereby we specify a view model and via a data template WPF picks up on the correct view to create.

Project structure is a class library (users) and WPF app (shell). Shell has a reference to users.

The users library has a standard view model / views folder set up and I've added a themes folder with a Generic.xaml resource dictionary (set to Page)

I've also added the correct theme info (None & Source) attribute to the assembly.

Yet for some inexplicable reason (the config is the same as other libraries in the solution), WPF refuses to pick up on the data template.

Any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: I suggest adding a sentinel value to the resources in your `generic.xaml` file--some value with a known key, like "test123".  See if you can load that value from one of your application's views using `FindResource()`.  That should at least tell you if the dictionary is being loaded and merged.  If it is, the problem is probably with the template declaration(s) or perhaps with the ViewModel itself (Is it declared `public`?  Does it differ in some other way from the others?).

Comment: Done so, doesn't appear as though it's actually being loaded. There isn't any code anywhere that's loading and merging these dictionaries manually for the other libraries, so I imagine WPF picks them up automatically? The question is why it isn't doing so here.

Comment: Are the views declared in the same assembly as the themes?  If not, is there any code that would actually trigger that assembly to be loaded?

Comment: @MikeStrobel The views are declared in the same assembly as the theme. It's quite literally just a generic.xaml with a data template in it for view model type & view type.

Comment: @MikeStrobel and I've just tried merging the dictionary in manually in the App.xaml of the Shell app and it's still not working.

Comment: Does your sentinel become accessible if you merge manually?

Comment: Something is wrong here.  Is it possible your application is not loading an up-to-date version of the assembly in question?  Maybe that one project is not being deployed to the right location?

Comment: I've no idea what's going on, everything is exactly how it should be and configured like the other projects in the solution. I'm going to nuke the library (fairly new) and try adding a fresh one but this time use the WPF Custom Control library template and hope it's wired something up properly. Results to follow.

Comment: OK. So I added it as a WPF Custom Control Library and this time the "add new item" dialog had more options in it, but sadly still seeing the same issue. *sigh* mystery, unfortunately I don't have time for it, so I'll just have to instantiate the view directly.

Comment: What do the contents of the `generic.xaml` dictionary look like when you load it manually?  (You said you did this to merge into `App.xaml`.)  It seems as if either it's not loading the file you intended (or perhaps not the version you intended), or the file isn't being populated correctly, possibly because of an error loading its content.  Try removing everything except a simple sentinel value and see if you can reference that value.  Also try giving the assembly a specific version, and use the debugger to check `typeof(SomeTypeInAssembly).Assembly` to make sure it's loading the latest build.

Comment: @MikeStrobel That's all it had in it, still wasn't doing it. No idea why. Abandoning that approach now for now in interest of getting done. Colleague is investigating whether we're missing something.

Comment: When I asked earlier if the views were in the same assembly as the xaml resource, I meant to ask if the **view models** were in the same assembly.  If not, there may not be any code triggering the assembly to be loaded.  Try adding a simple static class and method that you can call on startup just to force the assembly to load.